# Close Bootstrap 4 dropdown on ESC

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

What's the simplest way using jquery to catch the esc key to close a Bootstrap dropdown?

I know I can use $('#dropdown').dropdown('toggle') inside a keydown listener but that opens the dropdown too and 'close' doesn't seem to be a method.

Comment: i think its a default feature no need to add this functionality https://jsfiddle.net/1cm4sL07/

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the open class from the dropdown

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
        $('.navbar .dropdown').removeClass('open')
    }
});
```